# Responsive Hexagon Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, css-shapes

I am trying to implement a Hexagon menu for mobile apps. The end result is

[image: Hexagon Menu]

My attempt is at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9084/).

The issues I am facing right now are:

1. How to make the Hexagon menu responsive so that it is always positioned at the center of the screen on which the app is loaded?
2. I want to move the menu activation button (referring to `id='menucirclebutton'` from the jsfiddle) to the center of the hexagon menu once the user clicks the button. Right now, I have added a class `menu-button-move`. How to make the menu activation button to be positioned right in the center of the hexagon menu regardless of the screen size?
3. How to implement the Hexagon outline that scales with the menu buttons on activation?

Comment: +Angular on your question tags might help

Comment: Would't this be more efficient when done with svg?

Comment: @JohnKeates Yes! it would be more efficient but I don't know how to get this done with SVG.

Answer (score 0):

For centering the menu on the page, please see: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

For the hexagon menu, here's an approach I was thinking:

1. Center all menu items. `position: absolute`.
2. `transform: translate` each item relative to the center.
3. For the outlines, create a pseudo-element for each item, `rotate` and set `transform-origin` accordingly.